# MySQL + PHP WHERE IN (list of numbers) only working for first number in list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following in MySQL/PHP

```
SELECT * FROM `uc_posts` WHERE `postinguser` IN (SELECT `following` FROM `uc_users` WHERE `id` = 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

The value of `following` is `1,2`

However for some reason it is only displaying rows where the `postinguser` is `1`

To confirm when I run:

```
(SELECT `following` FROM `uc_users` WHERE `id` = 1)
```

It returns the cell `following` with the content `1,2`

What's strange is when I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM `uc_posts` WHERE `postinguser` IN (1,2) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

It returns the desired result with rows with both `postinguser` `1` and `2`

The column `following` is structured as `varchar(255) utf8_general_ci`

Can you see what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE IN` does exact matches, it doesn't parse the result as a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store lists of numbers in a single column as a delimited list.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists; it is called a *table*, not a *string column*.

In your case, the value `'1,2'` is exactly what it looks like:  a single string.  It will match another string that has three characters, a one, a comma, and a two.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  If so, you could write the condition as:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `uc_posts` p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM `uc_users`
              WHERE `id` = 1 AND find_in_set(postinguser, following) > 0
             )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

However, I would encourage you to change your data structure so you can use a regular `JOIN`.  The performance is much better when you use the proper data structures.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Yes I'm still learning as I go, I thought it might have had something to do with the string element, that's why I posted about the structure of the column. Will remember this for next time.